# Is there similar tool in Illustrator that can perform this action?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, tools

Ok, so I have a project that I'm working on that needs these articles skewed in direction, hanging off the edge of an outline that is in red. I need to be able to cut the hanging part of the image off from the red border. In Photoshop, this can and has been done easily with the magnetic lasso tool.The only thing is that I need to keep the .ai format for this project and can't seem to find a tool that can replicate this. Any help is appreciated.

See images below for reference.

What is present:
[image: present state]

What the outcome needs to be while still in Illustrator:
[image]

Comment: its called a clipping mask

Answer (score 1):

A clipping mask is an object which masks other artwork so that only areas that lie
within its shape are visible—in effect, clipping the artwork to the shape of the mask.

step 1:
Place the picture to the artboard by selecting file--> place. select Embed from the tools option bar.

Step 2:

Draw the desired shape by using the pen tool or the shape tool.Make sure the shape you draw is in the front.

[image]

Step 3:

with the selection tool (v) Select shape and the picture, right click and choose make clipping mask.

[image]

or Choose Object > Clipping Mask > Make. (ctrl+7)

Thanks

Digiscape Gallery

Comment: Hey!Your welcome Eugene please go ahead and upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a clipping mask. Make an object of the shape you need (make sure it's on top). select the object and the things underneath it. Select ***Object > Clipping Mask > Make***. EVerything that extends past the clipping shape is invisible.

However, it's still "there" (as in if you select the clip group, the bounding box will be sized according to the largest objects within the group.

If you need your cropped image not to extend outward (even invisably), crop the image in photoshop and re-import it into Illustrator.